# to find a the running total for a column containing two project names in matillion ETL

Tags: sql, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matillion

[image][image]

I want to calculate the running total separately for two project names(menlo park and SFO-BAB) in matillion etl I've already calculated the running total for both the project names combined but I need to do it separately. I've added the screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to calculate a running total for the column UnitsConsumed for every projectName:

```
Select
projectName,
UnitsConsumed,
SUM(UnitsConsumed) over (partition by projectName order by reportingFromDate)
FROM waterConsumption
```

If you only want to see Menlo Park or SFO-BAB, you have to filter your result accordingly.